# AMQPConnector on Mule - SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: sockets, mule, amqp, connector

I'm working a long time with **Mule application** and **AMQPConnector**.
Before some days I saw an **ERROR: Too many open files**, crash, and can't send request till I'm restarted the Mule application.

***Mule code is something like this: (critical parts)***

```
<amqp:connector name="AMQPConnector" validateConnections="true" 
            doc:name="AMQPConnector" host="x.x.x.x" port="5672"
            password="xxxxx" username="xxx">
            <reconnect-forever frequency="1000" blocking="false" />
```

From flows:

```
<flow name="first">
   <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="order/submit" doc:name="HTTP"/>
   <byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
   <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
   <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
   <set-session-variable value="#[payload]" variableName="order" doc:name="Session Variable" />
   <set-payload doc:name="order" value="#[payload.info]" />
   <amqp:outbound-endpoint queueName="xxxx"                            
                        responseTimeout="100000" exchange-pattern="request-response" 
                        connector-ref="AMQPConnector" doc:name="XXXX" />
   <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
   <logger message="response from queue #[payload]"
                level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>

<flow name="second">
    <amqp:inbound-endpoint queueName="xxxx"
        responseTimeout="10000" exchange-pattern="request-response"
        connector-ref="AMQPConnector" doc:name="AMQP-0-9" />    
    <byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object" />
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON" />

    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_XXXX" host="#[sessionVars['partUrl']]"  path="#[sessionVars['path']]" method="#[sessionVars['method']]" doc:name="HTTP">
       <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="#[sessionVars['key']]" value="#[sessionVars['value']]"/>
       </http:request-builder>
   </http:request>  
</flow>
```

***The error exception log  is:***

```
2016-11-27 04:30:12,272 [amqpReceiver.1018] ERROR org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy - 
Message               : Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

Exception stack is:
1. Too many open files (java.net.SocketException) sun.nio.ch.Net:-2 (null)
2. java.net.SocketException: Too many open files (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync:349 (null)
3. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files (java.io.IOException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient:223 (null)
4. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:287 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)

Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:411)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:404)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

---

Request was accepted by http-listner and system stopped.

Maybe miss one configuration, or close connection....
(I saw same questions with solutions to increase system or add code in java class etc... - it wasn't help me, I don't have java classes. )

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Anypoint Studio. Unfortunately your operating system can only open so many files. Depending on your operating system this limit varies, however I experienced this same issue in both Ubuntu and macOS using the latest Anypoint Studio (5 to 6).

The best thing I can suggest is to restart and try and keep your open files to a minimum at any one point whilst using Anypoint. When I'm only working on 4-5 files at a time I can usually go an entire day without needing to restart.

With heavy usage I end up needing to restart within 5 hours.